# Modelling a directed graph in EF CF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, graph, ef-code-first

I'm having some trouble using EF Code First to model a graph structure.  I have a situation whereby numerous concrete objects within my application can be nodes that relate on any of a number of types of edge.

For example, two User objects may have a relationship (like, dislike, related to), but each could equally relate to another type of object ('viewed' page, 'liked' message etc.)

To model this within the application I'm using a base class of GraphNode from which all of the possible nodes will inherit, and each GraphNode has a collection of Edges.  Each Edge has a SourceNode, a DestinationNode and a RelationshipType (used for weighting).

I know how I would model this as a straight Database-first development, with a table for Edge that would have a surrogate key, SourceObjectID and DestinationObjectID fields which would be the PKs from the objects being linked, SourceObjectType and DestinationObjectType fields which are the type of object being related, but the site requires EF Code First implementation.

I've got it to a point where I'm using TPT inheritance, so I've got a GraphNode table with a PK that's the GraphNodeID, but it's then using this as the PK for each of the tables for the concrete types, in place of their own PKs which is going to cause problems.

Has anyone done this, or can anyone point me in the right direction for a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found out, inheritance is not a great fit for this scenario.

Other ORMs, like NHibernate, provide out-of-the-box support for "heterogeneous associations". Since EF does not, my solution is to handle this at the "service" layer (i.e. between the controllers/viewmodels and the DbContext).

What I do is create an abstraction that lets me store and retrieve elements (in my case, Notes or Comments) associated to any entity. I do that by manually storing the entity type and id of the referenced object.

This is mostly trivial except when you want to associate the elements with a non-yet-persistent entity (I handle that using some callbacks in my DbContext)

Comment: Sounds like pretty much what I've ended up doing.  It may not be as elegant as I'd hoped, but it's certainly a pattern I know to work.  I'm going to opt for a sort of node-less version, so my EF entity is just the Edge, with a SourceID, SourceType, DestinationID, DestinationType and RelationshipType and, as you've suggested, I'll have to handle the relationships away from the database based on a select by the specified type and Id.